# RunState: LUA_ERROR: [string "devils_catacomb"]:1: attempt to call field `get_devil_base' (a nil value)

Tags: lua

Hi my english is bad I have a problem

ERROR

```
SYSERR: Apr 11 14:16:12 :: RunState: LUA_ERROR: [string "devils_catacomb"]:1: attempt to call field `get_devil_base' (a nil value)
SYSERR: Apr 11 14:16:12 :: WriteRunningStateToSyserr: LUA_ERROR: quest >devils_catacomb.start click
SYSERR: Apr 11 14:12:32 :: RunState: LUA_ERROR: >locale/turkey/quest/object/state/deviltower_zone:1: attempt to indexglobal`positions' (a nil value)
SYSERR: Apr 11 14:12:32 :: WriteRunningStateToSyserr: LUA_ERROR: quest >deviltower_zone.start click
```

my deviltower_zone.lua

```
////////Error formed location/////////

function get_4floor_stone_pos()
    local positions,j,t = {{368, 629}, {419, 630}, {428, 653}, {422, 679},
{395, 689}, {369, 679}, {361, 658},},number(i,7), positions[i];
    for i = 1, 6 do
        if (i != j) then
            local t = positions[i];
            positions[i] = positions[j];
            positions[j] = t;
        end
    end
    return positions
end

when 8016.kill with pc.get_map_index() >= 660000 and pc.get_map_index() < 
670000 begin
    d.setf("level", 4)
    local positions,vid = deviltower_zone.get_4floor_stone_pos() 
,d.spawn_mob(8017, positions[7][1], positions[7][2])
    for i = 1, 6 do d.set_unique("fake" .. i , d.spawn_mob(8017, 
positions[i][1], positions[i][2])) end
    d.set_unique("real", vid)
    server_loop_timer('devil_stone4_update', 10, pc.get_map_index())
    server_timer('devil_stone4_fail1', 5*60, pc.get_map_index())
    notice_multiline(gameforge.deviltower_zone._50_dNotice,d.notice)

end
```

Comment: This is not related to the question directly, but you don't need to swap variables the way you did in Lua. You could just do `positions[i], positions[j] = positions[j], positions[i]`. This is because Lua evaluates the right-hand side, pushes both values to the Lua stack, and then attributes both values to the left-hand side.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of places where you use the `positions` table in the right hand side of an attribution to `local positions`. Lua always evaluates the right hand side fully before the left hand side, so in this context, `positions` refers to a global variable.

First occurrence: in the line:

```
local positions,j,t = {{368, 629}, {419, 630}, {428, 653}, {422, 679}, {395, 689}, {369, 679}, {361, 658},},number(i,7), positions[i];
```

you probably meant:

```
local positions = {{368, 629}, {419, 630}, {428, 653}, {422, 679}, {395, 689}, {369, 679}, {361, 658},}
local j, t = number(i,7), positions[i]
```

(although this won't work 100% because i does not exist yet -- it's probably better to just not use the `t` variable.)

And in this line:

```
local positions,vid = deviltower_zone.get_4floor_stone_pos(), d.spawn_mob(8017, positions[7][1], positions[7][2])
```

You probably meant to do something like:

```
local positions = deviltower_zone.get_4floor_stone_pos()
local vid = d.spawn_mob(8017, positions[7][1], positions[7][2])
```